# apt-get update prevented by signature failure

Tags: apt, windows-subsystem-for-linux, signature, openpgp

I am trying to apt update on my WSL

`sudo apt-get update`

but getting this error.

```
Err:6 https://linux.qmk.fm focal InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B748CC185DF5DA1
```

I tried out the below command as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852338/sudo-apt-get-update-failure) post suggests and tried different urls for `--keyserver`

`gpg --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu 8B748CC185DF5DA1`

and looked up openpgp

https://keys.openpgp.org/search?q=8B748CC185DF5DA1

but no luck there.

Is this something you can help me with please? Should I raise this as a [qmk_firmware](https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware) issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instructions for setting up other repositories often have a command to download the key from the repository itself. Apparently they did not publish their key to public keyservers.

Their GitHub site https://github.com/qmk/qmk_fpm has these instructions, including downloading their key:

### Debian-like, or Ubuntu-like distributions

```
# Add the QMK source to your apt repositories list:
echo "deb https://linux.qmk.fm/ $(lsb_release --codename --short) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qmk.list

# Add the QMK GPG Key:
wget -qO - https://linux.qmk.fm/gpg_pubkey.txt | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/qmk-gpg-pubkey.gpg > /dev/null

# Update apt:
sudo apt update

# Install QMK:
sudo apt install qmk
```

After that, apt seems to update successfully. You might just need the `wget` line to get the key, but verifying your apt source is probably a good idea now too.

---

FYI, here's how I found the answer. I don't know anything about QMK, so I tried a web search with site:qmk.fm looking for a mention of linux.qmk.fm but didn't find anything, nor did looking through their docs (briefly) turn up any info... you'd think setting up their repository would be important to document somewhere, but anyway.

Another search for `how to set up debian repository for "https://linux.qmk.fm"` found their github (one of them anyway, looks like there's several) and it's instructions mentioned above.